# Java 8 lambda expression or old way

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Hello guys I've got question about Java 8 lambda expression. For example I want to delete following id from class.

```
UserEntity userEntity = userEntityOptional.get();
for(Long permission_id : deletePermissionDto.getPermissionId())
{
    for(PrivilegeEntity p : userEntity.getPrivilegeEntities())
    {
        if(p.getId().equals(permission_id)){
            userEntity.getPrivilegeEntities().remove(p);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Similar to This code might be implemented in java 8 using a lambda expression.

```
userEntity.getPrivilegeEntities().removeIf(i -> deletePermissionDto.getPermissionId().stream().anyMatch(i.getId()::equals));
```

What I curious to know asymptotic of java 8 implementation of the same with the first block of code. And how do you think what the best way of implementation of this code.

Comment: This is a good question for discussion. But may be you have posted it to wrong forum :). As this forum is for question - answer only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second solution is faster than your first one.

- First is `O(n*m^2)` (If it works at all. I suspect `IllegalStateException` should be thrown if you try to delete any but last permission)
- Second is `O(n*m)`

Where `n` is size of `deletePermissionDto.getPermissionId()` and `m` is size of `userEntity.getPrivilegeEntities()`.

Best solution would be:

```
HashSet<Long> ids = new HashSet<>(deletePermissionDto.getPermissionId());
userEntity.getPrivilegeEntities()
          .removeIf(x -> ids.contains(x.getId()));
```

With score of `O(n+m)`

PS: Answer will be different if you are interested in actual performance.

Comment: You seem to assume a particular collection type for the result of `userEntity.getPrivilegeEntities()`. That’s fair, as the OP didn’t specify one, but you should should note which type you’re assuming. Likewise, copying `deletePermissionDto.getPermissionId()` into a `HashSet` is only necessary if it isn’t already a `HashSet` (I don’t know why the OP uses `deletePermissionDto.getPermissionId().stream().anyMatch(i.getId()::equals)` instead of just `deletePermissionDto.getPermissionId().contains(i.getId())`; I don’t know of any collection with a worse-than-linear `contains`).

Comment: @Holger Fair enough. If `userEntity.getPrivilegeEntities()` already `HashSet` there is no need in copying it.